# Illuminate\Database\QueryException : could not find driver

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Estoy en **Linux mint** y estoy tratando de hacer una **migracion** en Laravel y al momento de ejecutar **php artisan migrate** la consola me lanza lo siguiente

```
   Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : could not find driver (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = laravel and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

  at /home/ivandez/Documents/git/laravel/primerPaso/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:665
    661|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    662|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    663|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    664|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 665|             throw new QueryException(
    666|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    667|             );
    668|         }
    669| 

  Exception trace:

  1   PDOException::("could not find driver")
      /home/ivandez/Documents/git/laravel/primerPaso/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:70

  2   PDO::__construct("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=3306;dbname=laravel", "root", "", [])
      /home/ivandez/Documents/git/laravel/primerPaso/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:70

  Please use the argument -v to see more details.
```

Comment: Lo resolvi siguiendo los pasos de este post: https://askubuntu.com/questions/999999/php-with-pdo-mysql-in-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: Yo lo solucioné con este hilo:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42557693/laravel-pdoexception-could-not-find-driver

Comment: En el caso de que no te aparezcan las líneas, o que al descomentarlas siguiese sin funcionar.. (o que no utilices MySql) Debes buscar los archivos .dll que corresponda al Sistema gestor de base de datos (SGBD), descargarlos y añadirlos al mismo nivel de ruta que el resto de .dll. También deberías añadir una referencia a ellos, en el archivo php.ini.

Answer (score 4):

En Windows 10 con PHP 7.3.7 (cli)

php.ini (quítale la comilla de comentario)

```
extension=pdo_mysql
```

Comment: En mi caso necesitaba conexión con Postgres entonces mi linea fué 
 `extension=pdo_pgsql` y así dependiendo del motor de bases de datos que se quiera conectar.

Answer (score 1):

Si usan una distro de Linux tienen que correr en el terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install php-mysql
```

Y si usan xampp / lampp poner esto en el archivo `.env`

```
DB_SOCKET = / opt / lampp / var / mysql / mysql.sock
```

Comment: Si usan una distro de Linux tienen que correr en el terminal:

sudo apt-get install php-mysql

Y si usan xampp / lampp poner esto en el archivo .env

DB_SOCKET = / opt / lampp / var / mysql / mysql.sock

Comment: en mi caso solo ejecute la primer linea de sudo apt-get install php-mysql y con eso me funcionó

Answer (score 0):

Debes abrir el archivo `php.ini` en la direccion donde esta el ejecutable de php.exe que estas utilizando y hallar las lineas que dicen:

```
;extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
;extension=php_mysqli.dll
```

Tienes que descomentarlas quitando el ";" por lo cual quedaria asi:

```
extension=php_mysqli.dll 
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
```

Answer (score 0):

laravel en este caso PHPUNIT viene por defecto con sqlite como driver por defecto, hay que activarlo en PHP.ini para que funcione sin novedad.

Comment: Lo sería que proporciones un ejemplo para que la respuesta sea más completa

Answer (score 0):

Estoy usando *Linux Mint*, levantando el sv con *xampp* y resolví dicho problema haciendo lo siguiente:

1. ```
   sudo nano /opt/lampp/etc/php.ini
   ```
2. Descomentar `extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll`, quitándole el `;` y Guardar.
3. `php -v` (en mi caso tengo la version 7.4).
4. ```
   sudo apt-get install php7.4-mysql
   ```
5. ```
   php artisan migrate
   ```

Espero que te sirva la respuesta. Saludos